# Removing suggest this group to a specific friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-friends

I broke up with my ex but we're still friends on Facebook.

Is there a way to stop getting pop ups to "invite" them to do stuff?

Like "invite friends to like this page" or when Instagram suggests show people their picture is always on top of the list. I ask because they're always the first suggestion and it's getting annoying. I'd rather stay friends with them because I want to be able to "normalize" our friendship sometime down the line but the wound is too fresh to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any direct way to remove a friend from suggestion list, But you can unfollow a friend (remain friends) to not get notification and  to not see their name in suggestion list at top.

Note that unfollowing a friend will not show their activity on your timeline.

You can unfollow any of your friend at anytime, they will not get notified.